# CHECK: Show that the set $\{e^{2\pi xin}\chi_{(k,k+1)}\}_{k,n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H=L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Show that the set $\{e^{2\pi xin}\chi_{(k,k+1)}\}_{k,n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

First we will show that $\langle e_n,e_m \rangle =1$ when $n=m$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\int_k^{k+1} e^{2\pi ixn}e^{2\pi ixm}\,dx & =\int_k^{k+1} e^{2\pi ix(n-m)}\,dx=\int_k^{k+1}\,dx =k+1-k=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Now to show that $\langle e_n,e_m \rangle =0$ when $n \neq m$. Let $z=n-m$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\int_k^{k+1} e^{2\pi ixn}e^{2\pi ixm}\,dx & =\int_k^{k+1} e^{2\pi ix(n-m)}\,dx=\int_k^{k+1} e^{2\pi ixz}\,dx \\
& =\int_k^{k+1} \,cos(2\pi xz)+i\,sin(2\pi xz) \,dx \\
& =\frac{1}{2\pi xz}(\,sin(2\pi xz)-i\,cos(2\pi xz))]_k^{k+1} \\
& =\frac{1}{2\pi xz}(0-0-i(1-1))=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Hence the set is orthonormal.

Comment: Your set of vectors is indexed in two variables. You proved that $(e_{n,k},e_{m,k})=\delta_{nm}$. For a complete solution you nee to study $(e_{n,k},e_{m,p})$ for $k\ne p$. Otherwise your proof looks ok.

Comment: How would I do the next step? Can I just say that the next result is a generalization?